# Rewrite Rules & Google Search Engine

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a website located on

www.website.com

some of the pages have a rewrite proxy rule pointing to

sub.website.com
(a wordpress installation which resides on a different server)

so for example; 
**www.website.com/some-article.aspx** shows content from => **sub.website.com/articles/some-article/**
(and the address remains untouced)

The problem is Google will index both of the pages, which creates duplicate content.
I only want google to index this page: **www.website.com/some-article.aspx**

Anyone have experience on the subject, or got an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Several SEO plugins for WordPress add the canonical tag to a page that will tell search engines which one of your domains contains the official version. Once activated there should be no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most search engines now support canonical link elements in the head section, so on your sub.website.com wordpress installation, you would need to create a wordpress plugin that would add this element for each page, with the correct canonical URL. Something like:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="www.website.com/some-article.aspx"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want any content on the `sub.website.com` indexed, you can create a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) file in the root directory of `sub.website.com` and add the following entry.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

If you only want to restrict some directories e.g `/articles` change it to

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /articles/
```

If the root directory of `sub.website.com` is shared with any other site e.g. `www.website.com` , then see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945617/prevent-cookieless-subdomain-for-static-assets-from-being-indexed-by-search-engi/8945863#8945863) for instructions on how to modify your .htaccess to serve the correct robots.txt

Comment: > resides on a different server

Comment: i actually ended up with doing something similar.
i've created a robots.php file and made a rewrite rule to point 
robots.txt to robots.php.
robots.php than checks to see if the address was accessed directly or not, if it was it shows the "disallow: /". thanks. :)